# How to terminate session in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How do I terminate session in windows phone 8?
I have created login and log out method but whenever I click on back it
is showing details of customers,
So, how to abandon or terminate session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the back stack naviagation once you are logged out. This will prevent the app to go back if back button is pressed.

```
 while (this.NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
 {
          this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no term like session in windows phone developmen, However you can put a static variable in app.xaml and assign and check that variable everywhere

may be like this

```
public static string LoginVar=string.empty;
```

and assign it the value on successful login

```
App.LoginVar="User Name";
```

Make it back to empty on logout

```
App.LoginVar=string.Empty;
```

Check it anwhere in the app like this

```
if(App.LoginVar==string.Empty)
{}
else
{}
```